# What's the use of the derivation of an algebra?

Tags: differential-geometry

We call the derivation of an algebra $A$ an arbitrary linear function $\delta : \: A \rightarrow A$ such that $$\forall_{a,b \in A} \: \delta (ab) = \delta (a) b + a \delta (b)$$

But for what things do we use it? Why is it useful? Especially in the context of Differential Geometry?

Comment: There are deeper reasons why derivations are useful, but at a basic level, they allow us to define some notion of differentiation (which of course satisfies the Leibniz rule for products) in a purely algebraic context. This is useful in differential geometry when you need to define an intrinsic notion of a tangent vector. Instead of porting the usual calculus machinery to define the tangent space (which is perfectly fine), a very slick way of defining tangent spaces is as linear derivations on the algebra of germs.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thanks

Comment: In the context of Lie groups and Lie algebras, derivations are Lie algebra $1$-cocycles. This has many applications for the  theory of Lie algebras. For example, all derivations of semisimple Lie algebras (in characteristic zero) are inner derivations, i.e., of the form $\delta(x)(y)=[x,y]$.